# JavaScript global variable undefined issue

Tags: php, javascript, session, variables, global

I am somewhat new to JavaScript, and have been having an issue with a global variable.  I have a group id that is part of my php session variables, that I want to place into a JavaScript global variable so that I can access the value in JavaScript. But JavaScript always shows the variable as `undefined`, so I must be doing somthing wrong.  In a nutshell I have the following code:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">var group = <?php echo($group)?>;</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function clicked() {
      alert(window.group);
   }
</script>
```

When the `alert` window pops up it shows undefined, but I can tell by look at the source generated, as well as firebug that the value is being set to the variable at one point.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the value a string? does it need to be `var group = '<?pgp echo($group)?>';`?

Comment: This was the problem!  Thanks Matt!

Comment: Btw you want to avoid global variables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this kind of problem is to always call `json_encode` when printing a php variable as a JS variable. In your case, it would fail if your string contained a newline, or a quote

```
<script type="text/javascript">var group = <?php echo(json_encode($group)) ?>;</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.group = <?php echo($group)?>;</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result of `<?php echo($group) ?>` is a string then you'll need to put quotes in the `script` source like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var group = '<?php echo($group)';</script>
```

You don't need to use `window.group` to assign it as that is already the context of the variable.